# Html Entities in <a href=

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

My MySQL database has some fields that sometimes include an apostrophe, so I take care to encode html entities. For example "Cote d'Or" is stored in the database as "Cote d&039;Or".

When a MySQL query populates an href I get something like this in my source code.

```
<a href="/page.php?location=Cote d&039;Or">Text link</a>
```

However when I click on the link I get a 403 "Forbidden" error. On checking, hovering on the link says it is reading &039; as an apostrophe. That seems to be the cause of the page error as putting an apostrophe in the database produces the same error and having nothing in there works correctly.

My question now is, how can I have the html entity in the database and still get the link to work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

For URLs, you don't want to use `htmlentities()` as that's for displaying HTML.

Instead, you'll want to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
$link = '/page.php?location=' . urlencode($location);
```

If your data is already HTML encoded, you'll need to decode it before passing it through `urlencode()`. A good function for this is [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode):

```
$location = html_entity_decode($row['location']);
$link = '/page.php?location=' . urlencode($location);
```

Comment: While `urlencode()` is the correct way to represent special characters in URLs, when put them into HTML it still requires a call to `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`. The correct way to do it is: `$link = '/page.php?location=' . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($location));`

Answer (score 0):

You might be better using `filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)`

- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 0):

While not the best approach, since you are using `htmlentities()` you can use `html_entity_decode()`

From:  http://php.net/html_entity_decode

> html_entity_decode() is the opposite of htmlentities() in that it converts all HTML entities in the string to their applicable characters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the real problem wasn't the html entities. It was some of the security stuff written into Apache. A quiet word with my hosting company and they did something that made everything work (presumably removed a mod_security rule).

Moral of the story: if you get a 403 error, suspect Apache security first.

Thanks to the guys wh provided answers.